# How can I clone a subfolder of a git repository into another git repository as a submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-remote

I'm new to git and git submodules. Although I've done some research I can't seem to find a proper answer to what I'm trying to achieve.

So suppose I have a repository called Big Repo cloned locally on my machine that contains:

```
|- FolderA/
|- FolderB/
|- FolderC/
|- FolderD/
```

And another repo called Small Repo that contains

```
|- foo/
    |- FolderE/
           |- content.txt
|- bar/
|- other/
```

So what I need is get **only** FolderE from Small Repo and add it to Big Repo locally as a submodule. That is option 1. How can a achieve that? (and I need to be only "FolderE/", not the entire small repo or "foo/FolderE").

Option 2 is: since I won't be making any pull/push to Big Repo (I only use it locally to run some code) I can delete the .git folder or change the remote url so that it points to Small Repo, but again I don't want Small Repo to mess with the folders within Big Repo.

So my final structure will be

```
|- FolderA/
|- FolderB/
|- FolderC/
|- FolderD/
|- FolderE/
     |- content.txt
```

And when I run git push it only pushes FolderE and its content to Small Repo. When I run git pull it only pulls FolderE and its content into Big Repo.

What's the best approach to achieve this, assuming it is feasible?